# Is it possible to extract only particular values from a Dictionary (C#)?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is it possible to extract only particular items from a dictionary in C#?

For example,
I have an class called 'Information' which stores ID, Name and a number (string, string, double).
I create a bunch of objects of this class:

```
Information User1 = new Information ("Adam", "001", 10);
Information User2 = new Information ("Bob", "002", 15);
Information User3 = new Information ("Charles", "003", 20);
```

and store all of them in a Dictionary called 'Users' which in the end looks like this:

```
Key: 0 Value: ("Adam", "001", 10);
Key: 1 Value: ("Bob", "002", 15);
Key: 2 Value: ("Charles", "003", 20);
```

The question is, is it possible to get ONLY the 'double' values from the dictionary?

Comment: Side note: if the keys are sequential and have no relationship to the values of the dictionary, you might as well use a `List<Information>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a linq .Select() statement to restrict what you're getting

```
double[] numbers = Users.Values.Select(v => v.number).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ:

```
List<double> numbers = Users
    .Select(kv => kv.Value.Number)
    .ToList();
```